# Default php function that turns negative numbers in 0

Tags: php, math, variables, numbers

Is there such a thing?

for eg

```
$var = -5;
echo thefunction($var); // should be 0


$var = 5;
echo thefunction($var); // should be 5
```

Comment: @Peter: abs returns the absolute value of a number, not 0 if the number is negative...

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try `max($var,0)`, which will have the desired effect. See the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) for more information.

Comment: will it work if $var is not a number? (eg. a string, null or false)

Comment: @foo You can always type-cast your parameter to a number (eg. integer) if you want to a numerical comparison. Eg. `max((int)$var, 0)`

Comment: @foo: please see the examples on the page I linked to. As you can see, the behaviour with respect to non-numbers is well-defined, but may not be what you are intending. You should perhaps filter for non-numbers and only use `max` if you know its a number.

Comment: If you want to allow arbitrary arguments, then say `return is_numeric($x) && $x > 0 ? $x : 0;`.

Comment: @Dheeraj You are exaggerating, this answer is the best but other answers are not retared. I would like it if you would be more polite.

Comment: @Julian wow i dont know why i wrote such a comment, removed it now.

Comment: `max(null, 0)` will return `null`. Instead, use `max(intval($var), 0)`

Answer (score 5):

Not built-in but, here you have:

```
function thefunction($var){
   return ($var < 0 ? 0 : $var);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, checking if a integer is negative and if it is then setting it to zero is easy, but I was looking for something shorter (and potentially faster) than:

```
if ($x < 0) $x = 0;
```

Well, this is a very quick check and reset, but there is a function max that does this too and it works with arrays too.

```
$x = max(0, $x); // $x will be set to 0 if it was less than 0
```

The max() function returns the number with the highest value of two specified numbers.

```
echo max(1, 3, 5, 6, 7); // 7
echo max(array(2, 4, 5)); // 5
echo max(0, 'hello'); // 0
echo max('hello', 0); // hello
echo max(-1, 'hello'); // hello

// With multiple arrays, max compares from left to right
// so in our example: 2 == 2, but 4 < 5
$val = max(array(2, 4, 8), array(2, 5, 7)); // array(2, 5, 7)

// If both an array and non-array are given, the array
// is always returned as it's seen as the largest
$val = max('string', array(2, 5, 7), 42); // array(2, 5, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function thefunction($number){
  if ($number < 0)
    return 0;
  return $number; 
}
```

that should do the trick

Comment: well I was hoping there's a built in function so I don't have to create my own since this is not very big of a deal...

Comment: Worked to avoid negative values

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
echo $var < 0 ? 0 : $var;
```

Comment: that's not a function

Comment: function noneg ($num){
 return ($num < 0) ? 0 : $num;
}

Comment: that's not a "default php function"

Comment: Yes, three out of four answers don't fit the question. And have you noticed that @edgar has posted the exact same thing four years ago?

Comment: Edgar was creating a function but earlier foo had said "so I don't have to create my own (function)" so I suggested a solution without the hassle of making a function. You insisted it had to be a function that's the only reason I finally did but I can't make you happy can I.