# Is there a function for limiting values?

Tags: php

If I'm subtracting two variables and don't want the result to be less than zero, I can do this:

```
$diff = ($a-$b)>=0?($a-$b):0;
```

Is there a function for this sort thing? That is, defining a maximum or minimum for the result of an operation?

It seems like there would be something like this:

```
$diff = min($a-$b, 0);
```

But when I tried searching all that came up was stuff related to memory limits.

Comment: @Matthew Maybe my question isn't worded clearly enough. I'm referring to limiting a value (either a maximum limit or a minimum limit), whereas `abs` just returns the absolute (positive) value of a number.

Comment: Look at `min` and `max` in the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php, in your example, `max($a-$b, 0)` would give you what you're asking.

Comment: @Matthew those return the min or max value in a list or array of items, they don't limit the value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *limit the value*.  Perhaps update your question to include inputs with expected outputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566187/default-php-function-that-turns-negative-numbers-in-0

Comment: `if($var_diff < 0){ // kill it }`

Comment: @Nate note that a list of values is being passed. The highest one will be returned, thus if your input is a negative number, 0 will be "max". When using `min` your negative number wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$diff = max($a-$b,0)
```

remember, if `$a-$b` is negative, it will be < 0

Comment: Nice. This seems counter-intuitive/backwards to me, but it looks like `min` and `max` will work after all!